# CriteriaQuery list of abstract class

Tags: java, jpa, criteriaquery

I have the classes Order, Article, Car

```
public class Order{
private List<Article> articles;
}

public abstract class Article{
private int id;
}

public class Car extends Article{
private String color;
}

public class Book extends Article{
private String title;
}
```

How can I check the articles that are a car using criteriaquery?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that queries are polymorphic.

```
CriteriaQuery<Order> q = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
Root<Order> order = q.from(Order.class);
Join<Order,Article> article = order.join("articles", JoinType.LEFT);
q.select(order)
.where(cb.equal(article.type(), Car.class));
```

You can restrict the type of the classes using type() and the subclass that you only want to retrieve.

In order to obtain color attribute, you must execute the TypedQuery and iterate over it.

```
TypedQuery<Order> qw = em.createQuery(q);
List<Order> orderList = qw.getResultList();
```

from  `orderList.get(index).getArticles().get(indexOfArticles).getColor();`

In order to add a clause for the car color.

```
CriteriaQuery<Order> q = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
Root<Order> order = q.from(Order.class);
Join<Order,Car> article = order.join("articles", JoinType.LEFT);
q.select(order)
.where(cb.equal(article.get("color"), "red"),cb.equal(article.type(), Car.class));
```

Comment: and how can I access the color attribute?

Comment: Update in my comments

Comment: But I want to use this in a where clause.
I want all orders that have for example a red car?

Comment: I'm getting: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [color] against path [null]